# Why does adding thorium to a TIG welding electrode improve the arc?

Tags: material-science

Why does adding thorium to a TIG welding electrode improve the arc? What are the physics behind this and other tungsten alloys used for improving [TIG electrodes](https://www.google.com/search?q=tig+electrode)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TIG electrode needs to have the following properties:

- initiate an arc easily
- live long

You use tungsten as the main material, you get the high melting point and longevity of the second point. However, [the work function of tungsten is very high](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function#Work_functions_of_elements.5B11.5D): 4.3 - 5.2 eV. By contrast, thorium has a work function of 3.4 eV, and has itself quite a high melting point (1755 C) so it won't affect the electrode life too much.

The lower work function means that electrons will be emitted at lower field (for a given temperature) and this in turn will make arc initiation easier.

Comment: So then only the tip contains Th? Or is it alloyed throughout the electrode?

Comment: I imagine it has to be throughout - as the electrode erodes you want the work function to be unaltered.